# Does the datasource connection pool's maxActive limit the app's number of connection to the DB?

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling

If my datasource connection has maxActive to 10 such as:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxActive="10" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/abc_DataSource" password="p" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://NTxxx\\instyyy:12345;databaseName=dbzzz" username="u"/>
```

While one (1) Java app has 25 threads simultaneously connecting to the DB to do some work:

1. Will this mean that at most only 10 out of the 25 threads will get to connect to the DB simultaneously?
2. Effectively, does this maxActive of 10 limit the 25 threads and the remaining 15 will block / wait until a connection from the pool becomes available?

Comment: which connection pooler?